# Dropdowns not working in IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been trying for a while to get a set of dropdown menus I created working. From some of what I've read it seems to be an issue with IE not supported :hover on li elements. I've tried several methods including jQuery to resolve this issue and none of them have an effect. One of the weirdest things to me is that if I put the exact same CSS/HTML I'm using into jsFiddle it works just fine in all browsers but if I put it into a page and test it IE does nothing.

This seems like a such an easy issue to fix but somehow I haven't been able to find the solution.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);
#main_nav{
    /*background: #4cb6ea;*/
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font: 300 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    background: #333;
    margin: 15px;
}

article {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px #666;
}

section {
    clear: left;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1, #main_content, #dog_link {
    padding: 15px;
}

p {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

a {
    color: #06c;
}

#main_nav ul {
    /*background: white;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

#main_nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    /*width: 175px;*/
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

#main_nav li ul li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}

#main_nav > ul > li > a, h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#main_nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

#main_nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#main_nav ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#main_nav li:hover, #main_nav li:hover li {
    /*background: #ddd;*/
    background: #A0A0A0;
}

#main_nav li li:hover, #main_nav li li:hover li {
    /*background: #bbb;*/
    background: #353535;
}

#main_nav li li li:hover {
    background: #999;
}

#main_nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#main_nav ul li .active a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}


<div id="header">
<a href="/index.php"><div id='logo'></div></a>

<div id='main_nav'>
    <ul>
        <li class=''>
            <a href='#'>About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>News</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=''>
            <a href='#'>Town Departments</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Water Board</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Parks and Rec.</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Sanitation</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Streets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class=''>
            <a href='#'>Public Safety</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Fire Dept</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='/fire_officers-personnel.php'>Officers and Personnel</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/fire_training.php'>Training</a></li>
                        <li><a href='/fire_photos.php'>Photos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Police Dept</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Officers and Personnel</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>News</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>FAQ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSFiddle for direct investigation. Thanks.

Comment: MS dropped support in Jan -2016, user stats ~ 1%, why try fix an error on a browser like that?

Comment: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46tgw00e/3/)

Overall IE may not be widely used but I know many of the people using this website will be using older computers. Some of the systems they use also will not function on any browser other than IE10 or less so for them it's pretty essential. They could use a different browser for the site but I know many of them are not very computer savvy and would end up getting confused. Even if it was a small amount though I'd still rather I site I build be functional on almost any browser than people visit a site with my name on it and it be completely unusable.